# Remove element if last

Tags: jquery, replace, html-table

I don't know if this is even possible but we'll see...

I have a table:

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="stripey">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="center"></td>
                    <td>Plan Name</td>
                    <td class="options">Options</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo alternator('', 'odd'); ?>" id="record-<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                    <td class="center"></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                    <td class="options"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>inc/images/search.png"> <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>inc/images/pencil.png"> <a href="#" class="delete" title="delete"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>inc/images/delete.png"></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

as you can see, the `<tr>` is repeated for however many is in `$result`...  but I have an image allowing me to delete the item...  so I wrote:

```
$('a.delete').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/plans/delete',
        data: 'id='+ parent.attr('id').replace('record-', ''),
        beforeSend: function() {
            parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            parent.children('td').wrapInner('<div>');
            parent.children('td').children('div').slideUp(500,function() {
            parent.remove();
            $('.stripey tr').removeClass('odd');
            $('.stripey tr:even').addClass('odd');

            });
        }
    });
    return false;       
});
```

Now what I would like to know, is if it's possible to somehow tell how many `tr` items there are in the `tbody` so that if there is 0, I can replace the entire table with text stating there are none.

Comment: You shouldn't use `GET` for deleting things; use `POST` or `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the length property of the jQuery dom object...

```
if($('table.stripey tbody tr').length == 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: @Justin: in which case please consider up-voting, or accepting, this answer. ([faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below line to get the total no of trs in the anchor `click` event handler.

```
var totalNoOfTrs =  $(this).closest("tbody").children().length;

$('a.delete').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/plans/delete',
        data: 'id='+ parent.attr('id').replace('record-', ''),
        beforeSend: function() {
            parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            var $tbody = $tr.closest("tbody");
            $tr.remove();
            if($tbody.children().length > 0){
               $('.stripey tr').removeClass('odd');
               $('.stripey tr:even').addClass('odd');
            }
            else{
               //Replace the table with appropriate message.
               $('.stripey').replaceWith("<div>No rows to delete</div>");
            }

        }
    });
    return false;       
});
```

In the above code `this` points to the anchor element with `class` delete and closest of `tbody` will give the tbody element which contains all the trs and then `children()` of  tbody will give all the tr elements within it.

Comment: so in my case I would do:

var totalNoOfTRs = parent.parent().children().length; in order to get it.. worth a try

Comment: You can use the code which I have it in my answer as it is. `$(this).closest("tbody")` will give you the `tbody` element.

Comment: I tried that, it keeps returning 0 even though I have more than 1 in the list...  note: it will need to be run in the success: function...

Comment: I tried exactly what you put in plus parent.parent().children.length like i said..  but the one that Gisli posted worked perfectly.

Comment: Try this `$(this).closest("tbody").children().length;` and not `parent.parent().children.length`. It is completely wrong.

Comment: @Justin - Take a look at my edited answer, I have added all the necessary code. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `length` of the `children` of the `tbody`:

```
if($("tbody").children().length) {
    console.log("There is still at least one row.");
}else{
    console.log("There are no more rows.");
}
```